# How to write Component Test for the service class which uses returns Mono?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a REST API-based application in Spring Boot which used Spring Webflux. As usual, the REST call flow looks like this:

RestController -> Service -> Another Microservice (REST Call)

The Service class uses `WebClient` to make the HTTP call to another service and returns a `Mono`, like:

```
private Mono<SubmissionResponse> submit(Submission mySubmission)  {

  Mono<Void> 201Response = webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/submit")
        .body(Mono.just(mySubmission), Submission.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND), resp -> Mono.just(new SubmissionNotFoundException("No Submission found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name())))
        .bodyToMono(Void.class);

    return 201Response.map(r -> myResponseGenerator.generateResponse(mySubmission));
}
```

I have a wire mock server started during the Component Test. The test case code looks like:

```
Mono<SubmissionResponse> submissionResponse = submissionService.submit(mySubmission);
SubmissionResponse response = submissionResponse.block();
```

In the above test case code, the response object is always `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`Mono<Void>` can never emit a value, only a completion signal. Therefore, the `Mono<Void> 201Response` will not emit data, so `map` will not be triggered.

Try this:

```
.bodyToMono(Void.class)
.thenReturn(myResponseGenerator.generateResponse(mySubmission));
```

Here, the `thenReturn` operator will emit the provided value.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it worked. I have even added StepVerifier for test as well and its working. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ lkatiforis done